# Create a mini-delay before each recursion in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

For some of my foolish reasons and monotony, How do I create a half second delay before each recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal is right but if you don't need to receive any messages for readability use `timer:sleep/1`. This function does exactly the same.

Comment: yes, with exactly the same code (not exactly, it returns ok) :o)

Answer (score 2):

use the after statement of a receive bloc

```
wait_ms(X) when is_integer(X) ->
    receive
    after X ->
        done
    end.
```